# $L=-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}, 0\leq x<\infty$ with self adjoint boundary conditions $\psi(0)/\psi'(0)=\tan \theta$ for some fixed angle $\theta$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

Consider the differential operator acting on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$,
$$L=-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}, 0\leq x<\infty$$ with self adjoint boundary conditions $$\psi(0)/\psi'(0)=\tan \theta$$ for some fixed angle $\theta$.

a) Show that when $\tan\theta<0 $ there is a single negative eigenvalue with a normalizeable eigenfunction $\psi_0(x)$ localized near the origin, but none when $\tan\theta>0$.
[image]

If anyone could be kind enough to help me with any of these problem parts I would really appreciate it.They are way over my head right now and I need to somehow learn how to do them. :(

Comment: Here's a few hints. Part (a) amounts to solving the eigenvalue problem $L\Psi = \lambda\Psi$, and you need to consider cases where $\lambda$ is either positive or negative; one of the cases will give you eigenfunctions which are not normalisable. Part (b) is actually straightforward, you just need to substitute the ansatz into the eigenvalue problem and show that $\eta(k)$ satisfies the given equation.

Comment: The key to solving part (c) is to exploit the result in part (b). Since part (b) involves complex exponential, the obvious approach is to rewrite the integrand using Euler's identity. You should see that the integral separates nicely into two parts, one without $e^{i\eta(k)}$ (call this $A$) and one with $e^{i\eta(k)}$ (call this $B$). One of these corresponds to $\delta(x-x')$ and the other one better be $\psi_0(x)\psi_0(x')$. I will let you figure out how to analyse $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ there is a unique classical solution of
$$
        -f'' = \lambda f, \;\; f(0)=\sin\theta,\; f'(0)=\cos\theta.
$$
That solution can be expressed as
$$
             f_{\lambda}(x)=\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x)\sin\theta + \frac{\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x)}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\cos\theta. \tag{*}
$$
Assume the branch cut of $\sqrt{\lambda}$ to be along the positive real axis.

(a) The only issue of whether or not $f$ is an eigenfunction of the operator $L$ defined by $Lf=-f''$ is whether or not $f$ is square integrable on $[0,\infty)$. In terms of exponentials,
$$
     f_{\lambda}(x) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\sin\theta+\frac{1}{i\sqrt{\lambda}}\cos\theta\right)e^{i\sqrt{\lambda}x}
   + \frac{1}{2}\left(\sin\theta -\frac{1}{i\sqrt{\lambda}}\cos\theta\right)e^{-i\sqrt{\lambda}x}. \tag{**}
$$
Eigenvalues have to be real for this selfadjoint operator. You can use.
For real and positive $\lambda$, $f \notin L^2[0,\infty)$. If $\lambda < 0$, then $\sqrt{\lambda}=i|\lambda|^{1/2}$, and $e^{i\sqrt{\lambda}x}=e^{-|\lambda|^{1/2}x}\in L^2$, which gives $f\in L^2$ iff
$$
     \sin\theta - \frac{1}{i\sqrt{\lambda}}\cos\theta=0 \\
     \sin\theta +\frac{1}{|\lambda|^{1/2}}\cos\theta = 0 \\
     \tan\theta = -|\lambda|^{1/2}.
$$
So there is one solution $f \in L^2$ when $\tan\theta < 0$ and none otherwise.

(b) For real and positive $\lambda$, the function $f_{\lambda}(x)$ is bounded for $x\in[0,\infty)$, and may be written as
$$
     f_{\lambda}(x)=A(\lambda)\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x+\phi_{\lambda}).
$$

Comment: I was talking to my teacher today and he said we can’t assume f(0)= sin and f’(0)=cos from the fact that f(0)/f’(0)=tan... :/

Comment: @MathIsHard : Every solution where $\tan$ is defined will be a scalar multiple of the one where $f(0)=\sin$ and $f'(0)=\cos$. I've chosen a normalized version of the solution, which doesn't change anything, except that you end up with analyticity in the parameter $\lambda$. For example $\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x)$ and $\frac{\sin(\sqrt{\lambda})}{\sqrt{\lambda}}$ are holomorphic in $\lambda$. This trick is a good one to learn from a theoretical standpoint, and because it eliminates special cases through limits in $\lambda$ such as $\lambda=0$.

Comment: @MathIsHard : For example, look at my very first displayed equation $(*)$ and let $\lambda\rightarrow 0$ to get $f_0=\sin\theta + x\cos\theta$, which would otherwise be a special case to handle separately. Any solution found with normalization will be a scalar multiple of mine.

Comment: Oh perfect. Thank You!